# Normalise customer lifetime

Tags: survival, descriptive-statistics, censoring

We want to correlate customer lifetime (dependent variable) with feedback rating the customers leave (independent variable) to determine whether we can use the feedback as a prediction for customer churn.

Our data is in a format like this

[image]

I'm not a statistician but I assume that if we just correlated Lifetime with Feedback the results would be skewed because a more recent customer is less likely to have a longer lifetime. How do we normalise this data so that I can correlate (using Spearman's rank correlation coefficient in Google Sheets).

Comment: The area of statistics you are after is survival analysis. I assume you want to predict 'cancelled'. You might want to search Cox regression

Comment: You have censored data, the one not cancelled yet have censored cancelling times.